# How do you set the image for an ERC1155 token in OpenSea and Rarible?

Tags: opensea

I've created an ERC1155 token and am able to see it in Rarible and OpenSea testnets (Polygon/Mumbai). When I go to the collection in Rarible or OpenSea, the collection image is the default placeholder. Is there a way to update this image programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, testnets of these platforms are not reliable. sometimes they work and sometimes not.
under the hood both of them are using pinata as a ipfs platform and some CDNs to store the actual art and related files such as thumbnails,...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm asking about the collection's image, though. Not the individual NFT images. I haven't been able to find any documentation on how the marketplaces set this image. The NFT itself shows the image correctly, but the collection does not.